# Protecting Excel Custom UI Ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose is to write a VBA to check to see if the custom Ribbon button label was changed.
Upon Workbook_Open event, the vba will get the label value of a specific button of custom Ribbon and compared it with a hardcoded value in VBA. If they are not the same the vba would close the workbook.

For instance, you can get the value of the label of built-in command with this

```
    MsgBox Application.CommandBars.GetLabelMso("PasteSpecialDialog")
```

But how to get the value of the label of custom ribbon button? GetLabel does not do the job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each command bar in excel.

```
For Each bar In Application.CommandBars 
if condition = true then
  'Your code here

end if
Next
```

Comment: Hi Prabhat, thanks. It seems workable. Let me test it out and get back to you.

Comment: I can't identify the object reference of the custom ribbon and the control.

Comment: Have a look into this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141001%28v=office.10%29.aspx